# Eclipse: How do I restore the original project structure?

Tags: eclipse, directory, directory-structure

After checking out a very old commit of a project, I checked back out to the current state of the project. However, this somehow messed up my directory structure in Eclipse. Here is what the structure was before (and what I need it to be now):

[image: Previous directory structure]

And this is what it currently looks like:

[image: Current directory structure (incorrect)]

So here are my questions:

1. Is there some **quick and easy fix to get the directory structure back** to how it was? It seems like Eclipse still "remembers" what the structure looked like, but misinterprets it.

   **Why did this happen** in the first place and **how can I prevent it** form happening again? A few others I know had the same problem (which made them promptly switch to InelliJ rather than fixing the issue).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems your source folder is the project folder instead of `src/main` and `src/test` which can be corrected in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, in the tab _Source_.

Comment: @howlger Thanks, I had to set src as the source folder! If you turn your comment into an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the **project folder is wrongly set as source folder**.

This can be corrected in ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, in the tab ***Source***: select the source folder *Quoridor*, click *Edit...* and enter `src`.